# Do CSS variables not work for font face unicode ranges?

Tags: html, css, unicode, fonts

I want to define unicode ranges for many Japanese fonts. It covers a lot of unicode ranges, so I'd like to consolidate the property into a CSS variable to reduce repetition and clutter:

```css
:root {
  --jp-unicode: U+3041-3096, U+30A0-4DB5, U+4E00-9FCB, U+F900-FA6A, U+2E80-2FD5,
    U+FF5F-FF9F, U+3000-3003F, U+31F0-31FF, U+3220-3243, U+3280-337F,
    U+FF01-FF5E;
  --english-unicode: U+0020-007F;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Noto";
  src: url("./noto.otf");
  unicode-range: var(--jp-unicode);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: url("./roboto.ttf");
  unicode-range: var(--english-unicode);
}

body {
  font-family: "Noto", "Roboto", "Times New Roman";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>HTML + CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>It's raining today</p>
    <p>今日は雨が降る</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, this fails to work. Both English and Japanese default to Noto:

[image]

But if I inline the variable declarations, it's fine:

[image]

Is it just not possible to use CSS variables for this?

Comment: It is possible to use multiple values in a variable as shown in this link according to this site
`https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40font-face/unicode-range`